# Search other contributors in OpenStreetMap

Tags: search, openstreetmap

Is there a way to search contributors in OpenStreetMap ?

I need geographical search and search by name.

Any methods appreciated : API, via classical interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an "official" API to do that. But you could use the following external tools for that:

- http://whosthat.osmz.ru/ - search by username
- http://resultmaps.neis-one.org/oooc - search by location (activity center)